# how to save time as timestamp in influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I want save time as timestamp format from influxdb admin interface .but is not possible it show time in date format

{"database":"mydb",
"retentionPolicy":"default",
"points":[
    {"name":"old",
     "time": -1422,
     "precision": "s",
         "fields":{"value":10000000}},
    {"name":"old",
     "time": 1422568543,
     "precision": "s",
     "fields":{"value":10000}},
    {"name":"old",
     "time": 1422568543,
     "precision": "s",
         "fields":{"value":100}},
    {"name":"old",
     "fields":{"value":1}}]
}

time    value
2016-06-30T06:32:31.0133595Z    1
2016-06-30T06:36:38.3625607Z    100
2016-06-30T07:24:59Z    100
2016-06-30T07:24:59.27Z 10000
2016-06-30T07:24:59.2700914Z    1

Comment: I voted this down for being badly formatted, and unclearly worded so that I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

By default, InfluxDB returns the timestamp in nanosecond Unix time.

If you want to get the timestamp if date format, when you issue the query to the `/query` end point add a query parameter `precision=rfc3339`.

For more detail see the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/write_protocols/write_syntax/#specify-non-nanosecond-timestamps).